# Live Stream Video using ffmpeg

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, live-streaming

I am working with ffmpeg . i converted [something1].h264 file to [something1].m3u8 file. with this command  `ffmpeg -i /var/www/html/video1.h264 -f lavfi -i anullsrc=channel_layout=stereo:sample_rate=44100 -c:v copy -shortest -hls_list_size 0 -segment_list_flags +live /var/www/html/vid/out/video5.m3u8`
 All i know the event type is VOD (video on demand) .

1. I want make my converted file into live streaming format. So if anybody come to my link he will see from the moment he came , not from the beginning.
2. how to make this live stream from chunk of video , suppose i have 2 video file , i want 2nd video will add in the live sream after the end of 1st video
   Any kind of help will be great

Comment: add the `-re` command before the first `-i` to process in real time.

Comment: i tried -re but it still creates a vod type file. i need a streaming . can you provide a example?

Comment: What about setting the hls_playlist_type parameter? Have you tried that?

Comment: hls_playlist_type 2 . i set but no result

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to add dynamic image overlay on live stream video input? Means we can keep changing image overlay after video stream started?